# md card content color change

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
    <md-card  class="md-padding" animate-on-change="currentCard" class="col-md-8" >
 <md-card-content>
 </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

How do I change the color of `md-card` or `md-card-content` based on a condition?

I need to change the color if `currentCard.redAlert= true`

Comment: Mention your condition in question, and update question

Comment: @SharanDeSilva: Updated

Answer (score 0):

use ng-class directive,

```
<md-card-content ng-class="{mystyleclass : currentCard.redAlert == true}">
</md-card-content>


.mystyleclass{
    color: red;
    /*css code here*/
}
```

Comment: Nup. it throws errror. Trying to assign value to a non-l value

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VKLKRo?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-card  class="md-padding" animate-on-change="currentCard" class="col-md-8" style="background:{{currentCard.redAlert?'red':'blue'}}" >
   <md-card-content>
   </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</md-button>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentCard = {
    redAlert: true
  };
  $scope.toggle = function () {
     $scope.currentCard.redAlert = !$scope.currentCard.redAlert;
  }
});
```